# （xpath ）The matching information is incomplete.Special characters exist

Tags: python, xpath, python-requests

```
import requests
from lxml import etree

url = "https://music.163.com/discover/toplist?id=19723756"
headers = {
    'User-Agent': "PostmanRuntime/7.15.2",
    }
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

'''
”<”、”&”
'''
r = etree.HTML(response.text)

l = r.xpath("//textarea[@id='song-list-pre-data']/text()")

print(l)
```

the l  last:
lLevel":"exhigh","pl":320000},"djid":0,"fee":0,"album":{"id":158052587,"name":"Sakana~( ˵>ㅿㅿ\n']

Incomplete Matching Information Due to Special Characters
How can I solve this problem?

==============================

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://music.163.com/discover/toplist?id=3779629"
headers = {
    'user-agent': "PostmanRuntime/7.15.2"
    }
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
textarea = soup.find('textarea', attrs={'id': 'song-list-pre-data'}).get_text()


print(textarea)
```

I've finally solved the problem
Use bs for parsing and do not configure lxml. Configure html.parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With HTML-Input, I often use BeautifulSoup – it seems to be more robust in terms of broken or strange data.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://music.163.com/discover/toplist?id=19723756"
headers = {
   'User-Agent': "PostmanRuntime/7.15.2",
}
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
textarea = soup.find('textarea', attrs={'id': 'song-list-predata'}).get_text()

print(textarea)
```

If you need a "real" XPath Expression, try:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree

url = "https://music.163.com/discover/toplist?id=19723756"
headers = {
   'User-Agent': "PostmanRuntime/7.15.2",
}
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
dom = etree.HTML(str(soup))
textarea = dom.xpath("//textarea[@id='song-list-pre-data']/text()")

print(textarea)
```

Comment: nice it's useful，If I want to use xpath matching, how do I use it?

Comment: sir I want to ask if I can jsonize successfully in windows.
However, in Linux, JSON will report errors due to special characters.
Do you have any experience in solving problems? the error:json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character at: line 1 column 54156 (char 54155)

Comment: this looks like a new question?!

Comment: Yes, I'm asking questions here for the first time.
I'm going to create a new question now. Haha.